# Shared Container App Group between Cocoa App and Widget doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

i'm trying to share a NSUserDefault between the Cocoa App and the Widget, i have set up this:

[image]

i have make the same setting in the Widget Target, then in the Cocoa App and in the Extension i access in this way at the shared NSUserDefaults:

```
self.defaultsValue = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.myapp"];
```

in the Cocoa App works, and i can read the variable inside it, in the Widget doesn't work, when i access for variable with the specific key are null, for example:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self.defaultsValue valueForKey:@"MyKey"]);
```

is null, how i can solve the problem?